# Xamarin (C#) : iOS 13+ : Status Bar : Touch/Tap detection

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hours of research and testing and now I'm doubting my coding abilities. So I turn to the community, please be gentle.

Prior to iOS 13, detecting the user tapping/touching the status bar:

```
    [Register("MyApplication")]
    public class MyApplication : UIApplication
    {
        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("************************************** TouchesBegan");
            // In this app, only touching the status bar gets us here so
            // do something
        }

    }
```

How can it be done in Xamarin (C#) for iOS 13+?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the current behavior with >= ios13?
As far as I understand your code, you created a callback for all touches somewhere in the application. Touches not done on the status bar where probably handled by the views and just ignored.

Comment: >= ios13 TouchesBegan isn't called. <ios13 it is. 
As a test I created a box. Added a touch gesture. Box was 100px in height. It's placement covered the 20px status bar. Tap on the >=21 px and touch gesture event is called. 0-20 px it isn't.

Yet. Twitter and DuckDuckGo apps on > ios13 still have scroll to top via status bar touch. So either I am not understanding how to do it, or apps like those got an exception?